# Using of google fonts on my project. Is I need some legal actions?

Tags: gpl-3, apache-2.0

On my site I am using this fonts Roboto and Open Sans from Google Font which available under Apache 2.0 License. I added special link to source code of index page. Than I published code on GitHub under GPLv3. Is publishing of site source code optional or necessary? Is I must publish code under open-source license and create link to original source license of this fonts in root of my repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fonts are free to use, so simple use should not need anything special.

As a courtesy to users and would-be hackers that look at modifying your code, you should add a note (e.g. in a `README` file) that you are using fonts/code, instructions on how to get them and add the relevant licenses.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Should I (means I must some, like an obligation) or I may (means my free will: may do it or don't do it cause don't want) create repository under compatible license? Should I (means I must some, like an obligation) or I may (means my free will: may do it or don't do it cause don't want) create notice about these fonts in my repository?

Answer (score 1):

No, You don't need to do anything.

Comment: Welcome to OS.SE!  As for your answer, I'm definitely not disagreeing with you, but we do prefer answers here that give a little insight into *why* you think that.  Perhaps link to and quote from the licence?  Or point to an article about the licensing terms for Google fonts?  That way your answer can be of help to more people than the original poster, and is more likely to get upvoted.

Comment: Thank you for answers!